# How can I make my PHP script log the IP of all visiters?

Tags: php, html, logging

I have a script that I am working on in PHP that logs IP Address's of visters that go to that specific page. This is just a prototype. The script that I have concocted is working, but when it creates the TXT file containing the IP's it only does one line. How can I make it keep adding a line for every visitor regardless if they are a repeat visitor. I am not really sure how to go about that part, I am new to PHP.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?PHP
    $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    $date = date("d") . " " . date("F") . " " . date("Y");
    $intofile = $ip . "n" . $date;
    $hfile = fopen("ip-address.txt", "w");
    fwrite($hfile, $intofile);
    fclose($hfile);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html language="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>IP Address Logging Software</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Source/Stylesheet/DefaultPage.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Source/Stylesheet/DefaultPage.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Source/Stylesheet/DefaultPage.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Source/Javascript/DefaultScript.css"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Source/Javascript/DefaultScript.css"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Source/Javascript/DefaultScript.css"></script>
    </head>
    <body language="en-us">
        <?PHP
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            echo "<strong>Your IP Address <em>$ip</em> Has Been Logged</strong>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not use the apache ``access.log`` and filter by url. much faster and no extra implementation necessary. don't use ``getenv`` this is deprecated use ``$_SERVER``

Comment: flat files dont scale for storage, why not use a db

Comment: @dagon: because apache writing to a flat-file access_log is a lot "cheaper" computationally than trying to stuff into a database.

Comment: As an FYI, write the log outside of the public directory so users can't access it.

Comment: @MarcB i voted that up, my first pick would be to use the Apache access log, 2nd a db

Comment: Lan: Good Idea... I will put the log into another DIR that is password protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$hfile = fopen("ip-address.txt", "w");
```

Refer to the manual for [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'w'    Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.

Everytime you open the file it is being truncated.  Use the `'a+'` instead, or another one that will open the file and append, rather than delete what's already there.

Comment: lot easier to just use `file_put_contents('ip-address.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: So, if I replace the "w" with "a+" it will create another line in the txt file and log the next ip...? Instead of It rewriting the file every time and only keeping one ip at a time.

Comment: yes, I personally would follow @Marc B's advice, however.

Comment: dustin look at the fopen documentation

Comment: @DustinAngeletti: http://php.net/fopen just go read the docs. they CLEARLY explain what all the options do.

Comment: At the moment I am going with your first post watcher. Later I will probably change it more. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use file_put_contents (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Its basically a helper function that does the same as calling `fopen()`,`fwrite()`, and `fclose()`.

And to make sure that it appends the content just add the `FILE_APPEND` flag:

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', 'Hello World', FILE_APPEND);
```